# Using a delegate to add a listviewitem from a backgroundworker

Tags: vb.net, listview, delegates

I'm using a background worker to add images from an imagelist to a listview using a delegate because I want to load the images using the Async method of the background worker. I dont want my app to freeze while loading 100 to 4000 images. My problem is that the listview doesn't add an image one by one like I would like. It just does nothing then all of the sudden the pictures show up. The problem with that is that the user will be waiting for a long a long time wondering if any pictures are loading. I need them to be add one by one.

Here's my code:

```
    j = 0
    For j = 0 To lstPhotos.Count - 1
        Dim delAddListViewItem As AddListViewItemDelegate = AddressOf AddListViewItem
        delAddListViewItem.Invoke("", j)
    Next

Private Delegate Sub AddListViewItemDelegate(text As String, index As Integer)

Private Sub AddListViewItem(text As String, index As Integer)
    If ListViewMain.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim delAddListViewItem As New AddListViewItemDelegate(AddressOf AddListViewItem)
        ListViewMain.Invoke(delAddListViewItem, New Object() {text, index})
    Else
        Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(text)
        ListViewMain.Items.Add(lvi.Text, index)
    End If
End Sub
```

How do I get the listview to add images individually instead of all at once?
.Update and .Refresh do nothing. I should also add that the listview control is programmatically added to a tabcontrol and it's doublebuffered along with the main form.

Comment: be sure you are solving the right problem.  If the images are already in an imagelist, there is no loading involved (or at least none that you can do anything about).  You might add them as needed to spread out the load and not load more than you need.  Does it actually freeze with a lot of items?  the LV will only paint/draw the items which show initially, which seems like it should include the associated image.  It might be in initializing the image list.  Also, look into the VirtualMode which seems apt if there will be 4000 items.

Comment: @Pluntonix: I tried changing the virtual mode and virtual size but it just led to errors. Every time I've added pictures from an imagelist I've never ran into a problem. I don't know if it's for/next loop or the delegate. I've never tried to add images from a backgroundworker either. I'm just an intermediate programmer.

Comment: Here is how to use Virtual Mode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052475/how-to-populate-listview-with-a-lot-of-information-without-blocking

Comment: Please see my answer here, it's the same principle... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24421503/adding-150-000-records-to-a-listview-without-freezing-ui/24422586#24422586